# Landscape Orientation issue UIView and UIWindow in iOS 8

Tags: ios, ios8.1, xcode6.1.1

In my application, we support both portrait and landscape based the screens. when we push or navigate to portrait mode to landscape mode screen, then some portion of UIView doesn't has user interaction, popover controller view also presented in wrong orientation. This is weird issue ever i had. Please help me to get out of this complicated issue.

Comment: A code would be useful

Comment: newViewController = [[[NSClassFromString(moduleName) alloc] init] autorelease]; <br/>  [self.mainNavController pushViewController:newViewController animated:NO];

Comment: i am not able to post or share image here. To post image i need 50 reputation. That is why i didn't shared the screen shot of issue.

Comment: Hi guys here the dropbox url for the screen shot of issue. Please have a look and let me know your thoughts and comments. https://www.dropbox.com/s/xx6hlk1nmfyk0p1/Screen%20Shot%202015-02-12%20at%202.51.43%20pm.png?dl=0